# React - Does pagination implemented only on client not backend increase performance?

Tags: reactjs, pagination, large-data

There is many frontend libraries that implement pagination on the frontend (but not on backend). Instead of rendering an entire data list at once you split it. I do not understand how that can increase performance, because you still have to fetch entire data or does fetching large data set AND rendering large sets at once both decrease performance? Isn't the fetching what's decreasing performance not just rendering?!
Thank you!

Comment: Rendering large amounts of components can definitely impact performance. This is the motication behind stuff like virtualized lists: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized

Comment: Your questions starts from an incorrect premise. Pagination should almost always be done on the backend first.

Comment: and i asked because i wanted to understand if pagination is NOT done on the backend first, if there is any benefit of having an only client side implemented pagination like i said in y post

Comment: As @sunero4 said, rendering a very high amount of items can slow down the UI, depending on how complex they are. It's also a UX issue, much easier for users to page than find their way through 5K rows. But backend pagination is more impactful usually, since that involves the fetching and preparation of the data, as well as the actual transfer time.

Answer (score 0):

You Don't have to fetch the entire data... in most cases, this is how pagination on the client-side works :

imagine you have a table that has pagination and each time the table shows only 10 rows

so the first time you fetch the data for 10 rows.

when you click on the Next button
it should fetch the data for the next 10 rows and so on ...

this way it:

- fetch only 10 data.
- render only 10 data.

Comment: but i can only fetch data for the next 10 rows if that is made possible in the backend. if the backend just returns to me the entire data, i cannot just implement pagination on client and always fetch 10, then i have no other choice but fetching everything